# Database error, do i need to worry about it?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql, database

I am getting this error in my error_log file. Do I need to worry about it? Although, I am having broken image link problems and SEF problems on some pages.

```
[06-Sep-2014 20:55:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_close() [<a href='function.mysqli-close'>function.mysqli-close</a>]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home2/mysite/public_html/libraries/joomla/database/driver/mysqli.php on line 210
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in Joomla 3.3+ line 210 is in the `disconnect()` method the the `JDatabaseDriverMysqli` class, it's literally the `msqli_close()` call in the method shown below.

```
/**
 * Disconnects the database.
 *
 * @return  void
 *
 * @since   12.1
 */
public function disconnect()
{
    // Close the connection.
    if ($this->connection)
    {
        foreach ($this->disconnectHandlers as $h)
        {
            call_user_func_array($h, array( &$this));
        }

        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    }

    $this->connection = null;
}
```

If you're only getting the error on this line it may not be an issue but it's likely you're getting the same error on other line numbers as well. This indicates that due to server resource issue (e.g. memory or processing timeouts/limitations) the PHP instance isn't getting a valid response from `msqli`.

I would ask your hosting provider to investigate.

Comment: Thank you so much. I emailed to hosting provider. Lets see what they reply.

Comment: @Naeem, I have a mysqli_close() warning on a site that I host. What response did your host give you that solved the issue?

Comment: I did not contact with Hosting Provider, an extension and cache were making the problem.